# Slanted Corner on CSS box

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have been playing with CSS for only a short time and am trying to have a normal box but with the top left hand corner cut off at a 45 degree angle. Not a small amount either; I'm looking at a quite large corner cut at that angle. This effect:

[image: http://tadesign.net/corner.jpg]

How should I go about it?

Comment: What is this box for?  Will it contain text?  Do you want the text to flow against the chopped corner?

Comment: Honestly, i would go with either a normal transparent bg image Or a masking transparent background image to the corner only. You seem to want css solution and it just so happens that these do involve css :)

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004821/how-can-i-make-a-css-only-speech-bubble-with-a-border

Comment: you can use `skew` [http://jsfiddle.net/46Sak/]

Comment: an online generator: https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/

Answer (score 20):

## Descriptions

Slantastic (http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo.html) supports old browsers. For CSS3-specific, try CSS polygons: https://alastairc.uk/2007/02/dissecting-css-polygons/.

## Code

The HTML:

```
<div class="cornered"></div>
<div class="main">Hello</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.cornered {
    width: 160px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid red;
    border-right: 40px solid white;
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/mdQzH/

## Alternative Code

To use transparent borders and text in the border section... The HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="cornered">It's possible to put text up here, too
    but if you want it to follow the slant you have to stack
    several of these.</div>
<div class="main">Hello hello hello hello
hello hello hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.outer {
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: x-small;
}
.cornered {
    width: 176px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid red;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
.main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0 8px;
}
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/76EUw/2

Comment: The box will contain well the whole content of the site. Im looking also to use the space below the corner, which is where im noticing that CSS is stopping me. Not to sure if CSS will hold the answer any more, but still hoping :)

Comment: ahh, yea i see. thats great.
i am hoping to get right into that corner with content tho :S

Comment: Improved fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/76EUw/2/   Is this a little better?  Does the comment about stacking make sense?

Comment: yea thats makes sense with stacking them...thats great. Thanks a ton, 1st time on stackoverflow..defo coming back :)

Answer (score 17):

This can be done using svg `clip-path`.

**Advantages:**

1. Work with a regular div
2. No hacky borders to create shapes
3. Do not apply any rotation so that you can easily do it on non uniform background
4. Does not add any div element through CSS so that you can still work with the regular div background (in case you have code modifying it for example!)

The following CSS will shape the div with the bottom right corner cut off so that you can put any background:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 65%, 54% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 65%, 54% 100%, 0 100%, 0 0);
```

There are multiple SVG generators online:

- http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
- http://cssplant.com/clip-path-generator

**Support:**

- Firefox: 3.5+
- Chrome: 24+
- Safari: 7+
- Opera: 15+
- Edge: 76+
- IE: None

Check https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: This worked the best for me.  Is there a way to make this mobile responsive?

Comment: Not a solution. Support is terrible. avoid this until better support is enabled

Answer (score 3):

In the near future you could achieve this with [the CSS Shapes Module](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-shapes/).

With the `shape-inside` property - we can make the text flow according to the shape.

The shape that we provide can be one of inset(), circle(), ellipse() or polygon().

This can currently be done in webkit browsers, but first you have to do the following: (instructions from [Web Platform](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/enable/))

> To enable Shapes, Regions, and Blend Modes:
>
> 1) Copy and paste
>   opera://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features into the
>   address bar, then press enter.
>
> 2) Click the 'Enable' link within that section.
>
> 3) Click the 'Relaunch Now' button at the bottom of the browser
>   window.

### If you've done that - then check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/eSMyV/4/)**

which looks like this:

[image]

```
<div class="shape">
     Text here
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.shape{
  -webkit-shape-inside: polygon(65px 200px,65px 800px,350px 800px,350px 80px,160px 80px);
  shape-inside: polygon(65px 200px,65px 450px,350px 450px,350px 80px,160px 80px);
  text-align: justify;
}
```

To contruct the polygon shape - I used [this site](http://betravis.github.io/shape-tools/polygon-drawing/)

More info on the various properties which are supported can be found [here](http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/shapes/browser-support/)

Answer (score 3):

CSS3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) can draw this background.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50px, blue 50px);
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(red, orange) no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50px, blue 50px);
  margin: 25px auto;
  padding: 50px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a responsive friendly solution of Ray Toal fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/duk3/hCaXv/

The html :

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="cornered">It's possible to put text up here, too
    but if you want it to follow the slant you have to stack
    several of these.</div>
<div class="main">Hello llo hello llo hello hello hello llo hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello</div>
</div>
```

The css :

```
.outer {
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: x-small;
}
.cornered {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 2em solid red;
    border-left: 2em solid transparent;
    border-right: 2em solid transparent;
}
.main {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0 2em;
}
```

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to do something very similar using only an additional spans and the effect is done via CSS.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/David_Barnett/9pmctv74/) to illustrate.

HTML
`<div class="more-videos">
    <a href=""><span class="text">More videos</span><span class="corner"></span></a>
</div>`

CSS

```
`.more-videos {
     padding: 20px;
 }

    .more-videos a {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #7f7f7f;
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px 10px 5px 15px;
    }

        .more-videos a span {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }

            .more-videos a span.text {
                padding-right: 10px;
            }

            .more-videos a span.corner {
                border-top: 15px solid #7f7f7f;
                border-right: 15px solid #4d4c51;
                border-bottom: none;
                border-left: none;
                bottom: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                position: absolute;
            }

        .more-videos a:hover span.corner {
            border-right: 15px solid #999999;
        }
```

I have included a hover style triggered from the parent. The 'border-right: 15px solid #4d4c51;' color is the one that needs to be different from the parent anchor background color in order to create the diagonal/angular contrast.