# How to create this effect with CSS3?

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve this type(img attached) effect(no radius) using CSS3 (the cut corner)

Is there some way to make this with border radius ?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slanted Corner on CSS box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box)

Comment: A simple google of 'css3 cut corner' works wonders...

Comment: @MarcoGeertsma, it's not the gavel image the OP is interested in but the cut corner on the translucent black box.

Comment: Why don't you take a look at the page you took the screenshot from, and see how it is implemented there ?

Comment: It's not straight forward yet, Lea verou created a preview of how should it be: http://leaverou.github.io/border-corner-shape/ It's a polyfill

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/76EUw/772/)  

Html code**

```
<div class="div-wrap">
<div class="div-sec">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, blandit quaestio corrumpit ei has. Ei hinc dolor referrentur est. Legere corrumpit scripserit ad his. Eu qui ludus noster efficiendi. Sea iisque eleifend euripidis ea, pri at habeo patrioque. Debet deleniti recteque ne ius, ut albucius urbanitas usu. Eu illum posse viderer sea, an nec percipit verterem, duo id eirmod suscipit tractatos.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.div-wrap {
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: x-small;
}
.div-sec {
    width: 176px;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 40px solid #000;
    color:#fff;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: http://cdpn.io/ABtqy
close enough.. but for this you would have to create and extra div just for the corner style.. and the body of the div with the text would be a different div... right ?