# Css tricks with div box and borders

Tags: css

I am trying to make a div that looks like this:[image]

Is there a way to do this with css only?

I have been trying to play this idea in jsfiddle

```
.box {
  background-color : red;
  position : relative;
  display : block;
  height : 50px;
  width : 200px;
  text-align : center;
  margin : 0 auto;
}

.box p {
  padding : 0px;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  transform: skewX(-10deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-10deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}

.box::after {
  content: '';
  height: 50px;
  width: 15px;
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -15px;
  left: auto;
  transform: skewX(-15deg);
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

It looks like i can play with the left and right, but i do not know how to do it with the bottom.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box

Comment: This [shape built by Daniel Wallingford](http://codepen.io/danielwallingford/pen/LygzH) is similar, except that the bottom is horizontal instead of the top. Maybe you can tweak it to fit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of one way to do it, which is using svg. [Here](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/branches/2.6/editor/svg-editor.html) is an online svg editor

The code below generates similar shape to what you seek. Jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/565EK/1/)

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
    <g>
        <title>Layer 1</title>
        <line id="svg_2" y2="198" x2="509" y1="198" x1="59" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
        <line stroke="#000000" id="svg_3" y2="197" x2="60.999999" y1="320" x1="26" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
        <line id="svg_4" y2="258" x2="497" y1="317" x1="28" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
        <line id="svg_6" y2="258" x2="495" y1="195" x1="507" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="none" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: How compatible is this with browsers?