# Best way in css to cut the corners of a border out

Tags: html, css

i have a video that i have overlaid text on top of. This overlay has a border around it, but the design calls for the corners to be cut out. [image]Here is an image of what i want to achieve:

Is there any way to achieve this white border with cut out corners using just simple css, rather than have a load of transparent html elements that are just in there to add borders to.

Comment: ... what text are you talking about? It's just confusing.

Comment: You can use multiple background using gradients

Comment: You can use CSS3 border-images. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Comment: this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `:before` and `:after` to draw some `border`s and play with the `margin`s / `width` / `height` a bit to get it right:

```
div:before { 
    content:'';
    border-top: 4px solid white;
    border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    width: 596px;
    height: 272px;
    margin: 10px 20px;
    position: absolute;
}

div:after { 
    content:'';
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    border-right: 4px solid white;
    width: 612px;
    height: 256px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1L9e22rh/)

Comment: Thanks guys, all good suggestions. I went with the pseudo elements solution just because it kind of has to work in older versions of IE. Will definitely bear gradients in mind though.

Answer (score 1):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/punox/1/edit)**

[image: Border without corners css html]

```
.video{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background:url(//placehold.it/500x300/f0f);
}
.overlay{
    /*Uncomment Bachground to reveal the logic */
    /*background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);*/
    color:#fff;

    position:absolute;
    width:400px;
    margin:50px;
    height:164px;
    padding:15px 0; /* remember 15 ...*/

    border-top:3px solid #fff;
    border-bottom:3px solid #fff;
}
.overlay:before,
.overlay:after{
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    width: 3px; /* same as .overlay border width */

    top:5%; /* This is also interesting */
    height:90%; /* Do the math */
}
.overlay:before{left: -15px;} /* :) */
.overlay:after{right: -15px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my comment: multiple background and gradient (it could be 1pixel image ) [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zEuyH)

```
<div class="cornersOff"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/640/480/cats/1"/></div>
```

and CSS

```
.cornersOff {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block; /* or table or float or width or whatever*/
}
.cornersOff img,
/* not an image ? */ .cornersOff > * {
  display:block;/* or vertical-align:top for inline-block element*/
}
.cornersOff:before {
  content:'';
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  border:solid 10px transparent;/* size here tells how far from borders you want to see these new borders drawn */
  box-sizing:border-box;/* include that border width */
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(255,255,255,0.8)) top center no-repeat ,
    linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(255,255,255,0.8)) bottom no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(255,255,255,0.8)) left no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0.8), rgba(255,255,255,0.8)) right no-repeat;
  background-size: 580px 3px,580px 3px , 3px 420px, 3px 420px;
  /* it cactches the click event ? : uncomment this : *//* pointer-events:none*/
}
```

img tag inside can be an iframe, a video tag or just content.

If you experiment troubles with clicking, you can add to `.cornersOff:before` the rule : `pointer-events:none;` so it ill never catch the click event .... if that's an issue when you would set some opacity `background-color`.