# Slanted border using CSS

Tags: css, css-shapes

How could I style a div to like the below image?

[image]

Comment: There are lots of solutions for this already on Stackoverflow, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use half triangle with the pseudo element.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.rectangle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #003781;
  position: relative;
}
.rectangle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 0 25px 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #F8F8F8 transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle"></div>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5btv8e77/1/)

Comment: Oops! I should have refreshed the page before posting the solution.

Comment: @ManojKumar It is okay bro.

Comment: @ManojKumar We always move parallel.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="cornered"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.cornered {
    width: 260px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 40px solid blue;
    border-right: 40px solid white;
}
```

You will have 2 `div`s like:

Div `main`

[image]

Div `cornered`

[image]

**### Check it out.**

Answer (score 3):

You can use the pseudo element with a rectangle:

CSS:

```
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    #rectangle{
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background: #ac60ec;
        position: relative;
    }
    #rectangle:after {
        content: "";
        width: 171px;
        height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        border-top: 29px solid #ac60ec;
        border-right: 29px solid #ffffff;
    }  
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```

**Code snippet:**

```css
#rectangle {
   width: 200px;
   height: 100px;
   background: #ac60ec;
   position: relative;
 }
 #rectangle:after {
   content: "";
   width: 171px;
   height: 0;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   border-top: 29px solid #ac60ec;
   border-right: 29px solid #ffffff;
 }
```

```html
<div id="rectangle"></div>
```