# How to create a button with the top left and bottom right corner is 45 degrees straight angle?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, border

I want to create a button with the top left and bottom right corner is 45 degrees straight angle. Can such a button be created in HTML/CSS? Or I have to use the image? Please guide.

This is a button image.
[image]

and this is a code

```css
button{
border-style: none;
height: 60px;
background: none;
border: 2px solid #000000;
padding: 0 60px;
color: #000000;
font-size: 24px;
outline: none;
border-radius: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690168/slanted-border-using-css will help? or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box

Comment: 45 degree angle is 45 degree angle,
a straight angle is 180 degree angle.
45 degree straight angle makes no sense.

Comment: Yes you are right but, I mean 45 degree angle but not curve. As per image.

Answer (score 1):

Use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) polygon inside another:

```html
<div style="
background:black;
width:fit-content;
height:fit-content;
clip-path:polygon(
0px 36px, 
36px 0px, 
100% 0px, 
100% calc(100% - 36px), 
calc(100% - 36px) 100%, 
0px 100%, 
0px 36px
);">
<button style="
outline:none;
box-shadow:none;
border:none;
font-size:24px;
padding: 18px 60px;
overflow:hidden;
background:pink;
clip-path:polygon(
2px 36px, 
37px 2px, 
calc(100% - 2px) 2px, 
calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 36px), 
calc(100% - 36px) calc(100% - 2px), 
2px calc(100% - 2px), 
2px 36px
);"
onclick="alert('Hi!')"
>BUTTON</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that shape using `:before` and `:after` css selector.
I have added `span` in `button` tag and `:before` and `:after` selector in both tags to get this shape.

```css
button{
  border-style: none;
  height: 60px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 60px;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 24px;
  outline: none;
  position: relative;
}
button:before {
  content: "";
  width: 85%;
  height: 30px;
  display:block;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

button:after {
  content: "";
  width: 85%;
  height: 30px;
  display:block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
button span {
  display:block;
}
button span:before {
  content:"";
  width: 38px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;  
  left: -5px;
  top: 14px;
  transform: rotate(-46deg); 
}
button span:after {
  content:"";
  width: 38px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  bottom: 14px;
  transform: rotate(-46deg);
}
button:hover{
  color: red;
}
button:hover:before,
button:hover:after {
  border-color: red;
}
button:hover span:before,
button:hover span:after {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Button</span></button>
```

Comment: Please add explanation how this works - thanks!