# Containers have same undesired width

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-transforms

I have two containers that make up a transparent border that has a 45 degree angle in it. For some reason the second container maintains the same width/padding as the first container. I want the second container to maintain its own width/padding. Essentially, 30px of padding horizontally to each container, but not the same size.

What am I doing wrong? Here is a fiddle....[Click for fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1wmLayg/)

```css
.home-img-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13%;
  top: 25%;
}
#home-img-text-container1,
#home-img-text-container2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#home-img-text-container1.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}
#home-img-text-container2.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}
#home-img-text-description,
#home-img-text-description2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
#home-img-text-description:before,
#home-img-text-description2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background: inherit;
}
/*#home-img-text-description2:before {
width: 80%;
}*/
#home-img-text-description:before,
#home-img-text-description2:before {
  top: -30px;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
#home-img-text-description {
  font-family: 'open_sanslight';
}
#home-img-text-description2 {
  color: #efcd36;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-img-text">
  <div id="home-img-text-container1">
    <div id="home-img-text-description">WRECKING <span class="block"></span>& DEMOLITION
      <br>DONE RIGHT.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="home-img-text-container2">
    <div id="home-img-text-description2">YOU NAME IT,
      <br>WE WRECK IT.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Harry Here is the new question.

Comment: I can't understand what problem you are facing @Becky. If the `padding` needs to be different then change the `padding` property accordingly (and remember to change the `height` of the pseudo-element) or if `width` needs to be different then set the required width. For example, see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/r1wmLayg/1/). I just added a `width`.

Comment: @Harry I guess it isn't the padding then. Something is keeping the second container as wide as the first.

Comment: Ok, so you just want the second container (or all containers) to be as wide as needed, right?

Comment: Yes, right. Then whatever the padding is.

Comment: ?? i thought we answered this before or it is very similar ... http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ZWwOxV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions if you want each container to take up only a certain `width` (either a fixed width or the width it requires to fit contents). Currently there is no `width` specified and they are block level elements, so they expand as much as possible. The first container has a lengthy text and so it expands to fit the content (until the point where it cannot extend further) and along with it, parent (`#home-img-text`) also expands since that doesn't have any fixed width either. Since both containers are part of the same parent, the second container also expands to occupy the full width of the parent (as it is a block container). Thus both of them are getting the same width.

One of them would be to assign `display: inline-block` to the two containers like in below snippet.

```css
.home-img-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13%;
  top: 25%;
}
#home-img-text-container1,
#home-img-text-container2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#home-img-text-container1.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}
#home-img-text-container2.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}
#home-img-text-description,
#home-img-text-description2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
#home-img-text-description:before,
#home-img-text-description2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background: inherit;
}
#home-img-text-description:before,
#home-img-text-description2:before {
  top: -30px;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
#home-img-text-description {
  font-family: 'open_sanslight';
}
#home-img-text-description2 {
  color: #efcd36;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-img-text">
  <div id="home-img-text-container1">
    <div id="home-img-text-description">WRECKING <span class="block"></span>& DEMOLITION
      <br>DONE RIGHT.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="home-img-text-container2">
    <div id="home-img-text-description2">YOU NAME IT,
      <br>WE WRECK IT.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

The other would be to assign them an explicit `width` as required.

```css
.home-img-text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 13%;
  top: 25%;
}
#home-img-text-container1,
#home-img-text-container2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#home-img-text-container1.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}
#home-img-text-container2.fadeDisplay {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(30px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(30px);
}
#home-img-text-description,
#home-img-text-description2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  font-size: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}
#home-img-text-description:before,
#home-img-text-description2:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  background: inherit;
}
#home-img-text-description:before,
#home-img-text-description2:before {
  top: -30px;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  transform-origin: right bottom;
}
#home-img-text-description {
  font-family: 'open_sanslight';
}
#home-img-text-description2 {
  color: #efcd36;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
#home-img-text-description {
  width: 300px;
}
#home-img-text-description2 {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="home-img-text">
  <div id="home-img-text-container1">
    <div id="home-img-text-description">WRECKING <span class="block"></span>& DEMOLITION
      <br>DONE RIGHT.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="home-img-text-container2">
    <div id="home-img-text-description2">YOU NAME IT,
      <br>WE WRECK IT.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Harry and great answer as always! I wasn't aware block elements expand to meet the parent. Do you have any idea why the 45 degree transform wouldn't work on an android internet browser?

Comment: You're welcome @Becky. Regarding transforms on Android browsers, it should work as per Can I Use website - [2D Transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), [3D Transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) but I don't have Android OS and so can't test. Are you by any chance using a older browser version? Could you try including browser prefixes?

Answer (score 1):

`div` elements are inherently block elements. In most occasions they will take up the width of the available space unless set with an explicit width or floated.

To have these elements display in a width proportional to the length of content it contains, declare them as `inline-block`

**Example:**

```
#home-img-text-description, #home-img-text-description2 {
    position: relative;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    padding: 30px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    font-size: 2.5em;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give specific width to second container like below:

```
#home-img-text-description2 {
color: #efcd36;
font-size: 1.8em;
width:80%;
}
```