Text with slanted background
I want to have text (in this case inside a <h1>) to have colorful background, where the right and left boundaries are slanted. Something like this:

I know that I should do this by setting a backround like linear-gradient(102deg, #ffffff00 5%, lightblue 5% 95%, #ffffff00 95%); (which I used for this example), but I cannot get the left and right boundaries right. I think the problem is that I to need set start and stop values for the gradient (5% and 95% in this example), but that means that depending on the length of the text, the transition is "somewhere".


h1 span {
  background: linear-gradient(102deg, #ffffff00 5%, lightblue 5% 95%, #ffffff00 95%);
  padding-left: 0.8rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
<h1> <span> This is a title </span> </h1>



JSFiddle
Note that I manually had to play around with padding-left and margin-right to somehow make it appear okayish (even though there is way too much space right of "title"?).
If I make the text longer, the same CSS produces this:

This is probably because 5% and 95% of the <span>'s width are now at different positions, right?
What I would want is a solution that:

Always works idenpentently of the length of the text
Allows me to control the angle of the slant (12° in this case)
Does not skew the text itself
Works with multiline text
Does not cut off the slanted background (see the right boundary of the second example above)
Has a little space between the first letter and the left boundary of the background box, and the same amount of space between the last letter and the right boundary of the background box.

I tried setting the boundaries for the linear-gradient to 0.001% and 99.999% or something, but that essentially removes the slanted borders:


Possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059597/slanted-corner-on-css-box and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324722/cut-corners-using-css

Other possibly relevant links from google: https://www.google.com/search?q=css+draw+a+slanted+box+around+text

What you are locking for is the property transform: skew().
Just give the container its value and its child elements the opposite one.


.skew {
  background: #ff00ff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 60%;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  transform: skew(20deg);
}
<div class="skew">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</div>




The problem with this is that I want to control the amount of space between the text and the left/right border of the box. With this, the sizing of the outer div is way too big. I don't know of a way to shrink that div down so that the text of the inner h1 if fully contained (plus some space) inside the background box.

You can play around with the value of padding you can give each direction a diffrent value for e.g. padding: .5rem 10px .2rem 5px so this would read like padding: top right bottom left

@LukasBarth Check this fiddle. The div has width: fit-content and a small left/right padding. https://jsfiddle.net/4u3pm1wh/5/ it will adapt to the size of the content

Yes, with width:fit-content plus some padding, this might actually work, thanks! Now I only need to insert that div into the correct position in the flexbox-heavy template without screwing everything up. :) Your Fiddle-Link does btw not point to code with width: fit-content.

You can use skew property of transofrm.
Please replace background colour with your gradients.
Hope this helps.


h1 {
  padding: 2px;
  background: #000;
}
h1 span {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
}
<h1> <span> This is a title </span> </h1>




Thanks for the hint, but I do not want the text itself to be skewed.

In that case you can tilt the ::before of the text (span).

Or just wrap it in a div and give the wrapper the -20deg and give the text the opposite skew like transform: skew(20deg)

@NaeemAkhtar You mean use h1 span::before instead of the h1 span selector? Then I don't get any background at all. I guess the pseudo-child of the <span> just has zero width?

@LukasBarth what about https://jsfiddle.net/ansarinaeemakhtar/2chp1ug8/39/?

@NaeemAkhtar I think this breaks when the text gets so long it breaks to a second line?

@LukasBarth yes as I have used fixed height.  I think best approach would be of parent child element and setting one of those with skew property.

Just use padding-left and padding-right 5%, because that's the padding of the linear-gradient too.


h1 span {
  background: linear-gradient(102deg, #ffffff00 5%, lightblue 5% 95%, #ffffff00 95%);
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
<h1> <span> This is a title </span> </h1>




This looks great in the inline snippet here, but when I try it somewhere else (e.g. JSFiddle), I get way too much space: https://jsfiddle.net/3tnrca72/2/  If I reduce the padding (and the points in the linear-gradient to e.g. 1%, it cuts off the slanted borders…

@LukasBarth JSFiddle added further styling to the font of h1, notably font-size of 100%. Try without extra styling, if it works (and it will work, I think), then you will need to figure out which additional rules cause trouble and override/remove/fix them. If this answer solved your problem, then you may consider accepting it as the correct answer.



h1 {
  padding: 2px;
  background: #000;
}
h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
h1 span:before{
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  background:linear-gradient(102deg, #ffffff00 5%, lightblue 5% 95%, #ffffff00 95%);;
  left:-5%;
  right:-5%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  z-index:-1;
}
<h1> <span> This is a title </span> </h1>




This has the same problem as my original solution: If the text gets longer, it grows outside the slanted background box.

@LukasBarth not if you add left and right to -5% foe medium text and use -10% for large font, please check i have updated the snipet, try to change the left and right values according to the size of the font.



h1 span {
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent 50%, lightblue 50%),
linear-gradient(lightblue, lightblue),
linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 50%,lightblue 50%);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 10px 40px, calc(100% - 20px) 40px, 10px 40px;
background-position: left center, center, right;

}
<h1> <span> This is a title </span> </h1>
<h1> <span> This is a longest title that are highlighted </span> </h1>



You can try these, hope it might useful

That's a nice idea actually, just specifying the exact shape of the background. However, I need to exactly control the angle of the slant. I know, I didn't say that in my question, just updated the question. I don't think it's (easily) possible with this approach to get the slant to be exactly 12°, right?



h1 {
  padding: 2px;
  background: cyan;
  font:bold,italic;
}
 span {
  background: linear-gradient(102deg, #ffffff00 5%, lightblue 5% 95%, #ffffff00 95%);
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right:50%;
  padding-left:50%;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-left:30px;
  padding:10px;

}

  
<h1> <span> This is a title <span> </h1>



